# How to limit the upload size in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

On [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) is documented how to limit the size of an uploaded file in a form, **on the client side**. This can be done **in addition to any server side constaints**.

```
    <!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the
>   file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by
>   PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the
>   trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that
>   it was too large and the transfer failed. Keep in mind: fooling this
>   setting on the browser side is quite easy, so never rely on files with
>   a greater size being blocked by this feature. It is merely a
>   convenience feature for users on the client side of the application.
>   The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however,
>   cannot be fooled.

Is there a convenient way to do this in Symfony?

For example with the Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType.

Let's answer this question for various versions of Symfony, as I was not able to find something with Google for it.

Comment: File validation constraint - [4.1](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize), [3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize), [2.8](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize)

Comment: Also, searching Google for "symfony max file size" shows the above docs as result #2.

Comment: This will limit the size after the form was submitted. 
But if the size is too large, the $_POST field is empty $request->request anyways somehow contained the inputs. The for was submitted. But it did not validate. But all the input values where lost, when the form was rendered after that.

Comment: How do you expect Symfony to validate the size of the file, if your server config prevents the upload request from even being processed?

Comment: I think it should be possible to prevent the browser from sending sizes larger than post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in the first place and use the validation constraint later to restrict the file size with reference to the application's needs.

Comment: If I understand the information given from above right, you can prevent the browser from sending too large files. I expect symfony to add/provide a parameter to the FileType which results in such a hidden form input field at my html page.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your question. However client side hints like that are easily bypassed, so shouldn't be used exclusively. You'd want other checks in place too.

Answer (score -1):

Use the FileType field with the maxSize option from the [File constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html)

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you misunderstood the question. In the comments of the question is discussed why the File constaint does not do what I ask for.

Answer (score -1):

Do like this :

```
{
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 * )
 */
protected $File;
```

}